# Jboss Audit.log files are not being made

Tags: logging, jboss, rotation, middleware, audit

I have frequently observed the issue where audit.log files are not being made in the production JBOSS environment. Jboss Process is running and there is disk space is available.
Any clues on what the issue could be?

OS: RHEL 7.4

Answer (score 0):

`Hello`, you need to enable it first:

```
 /core-service=management/access=audit/logger=audit-log:write-attribute(name=enabled,value=true)
```

Be aware of the verbosity, `audit.logs`, are very verbose. In case nothing is written, see 1. See if the audit log is **actually** enabled in the configuration and 2.the permissions for the directory are good.

Comment: Audit logs are enabled and they are being printed, but sometimes they just stop printing. They only resume once I restart the jboss service.